# "Faulted: Failure sending email" in Elsa Workflow Dotnet Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, smtp, elsa-workflows

I am trying to run elsa workflow in dotnet core. The flow is displayed in [image: flow]. The error is in the third step [image: error]. I tried some solutions but in vein. I am using smtp and trying to send email to my gmail account. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer to the steps of this article, maybe it will help you: https://mycodebit.com/send-emails-in-asp-net-core-5-using-gmail-api/

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be to download the source code and reference the source projects directly. This way, you'll be able to attach a debugger and have it break on the exception (presuming the failure is caused by an exception rom the SMTP client).

As a side note: Elsa 1 is no longer being maintained. If you can, perhaps you might consider migrating to Elsa 2.